# Rename [amber] to [chronicles-of-amber]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [amber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amber) tag has 11 questions and no tag wiki. Every question appears to be about Roger Zelazny’s *Chronicles of Amber*, rather than, say, fossilized tree resin containing Jurassic mosquitoes. Should we rename [amber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amber) to [chronicles-of-amber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-amber)?

Comment: I've written a tag wiki. Feel free to update or revise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Done.

[chronicles-of-amber](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronicles-of-amber)

Feel free to [write a tag wiki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1890) for the new tag.

Comment: I've added a tag wiki and excerpt. It got auto-approved due to my rep, but feel free to go in and review.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I'd never heard of the series before, so I'm not much of a judge, but your tag wiki looks good :-)

Comment: Add stat-complete tag?

Comment: @Mithrandir Good idea; done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, good idea. Much clearer and doesn't need a tag wiki to explain its purpose. (Although it should get one nonetheless).